# Don't sort, but keep the sort as entered

Tags: php, sorting

I know this maybe is a very odd question but we are using a plug-in where we can adjust some templates. We have this template and it is sorting by price:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly ?>
<?php
/*
  Name: Sorted list
 */
  use Keywordrush\AffiliateEgg\TemplateHelper; 
?>
<?php if (isset($title) && $title): ?>
    <h3 class="cegg-shortcode-title"><?php echo esc_html($title); ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
// sort items by price
usort($items, function($a, $b) {
    if (!$a['price_raw']) return 1;
    if (!$b['price_raw']) return -1;
    return $a['price_raw'] - $b['price_raw'];
});
$product_price_update = $items[0]['last_update'];
?>

<div class="rh_listoffers rh-shadow2 padd20 border-lightgrey-double">
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($items as $key => $item): ?>
        <?php $offer_price = (!empty($item['price'])) ? $item['price'] : ''; ?>
        <?php $offer_price_old = (!empty($item['price'])) ? $item['old_price'] : ''; ?>
        <?php $offer_post_url = $item['url'] ;?>
        <?php $afflink = apply_filters('rh_post_offer_url_filter', $offer_post_url );?>
        <?php $aff_thumb = $item['img'] ;?>
        <?php $offer_title = wp_trim_words( $item['title'], 10, '...' ); ?>
        <?php $offer_desc = $item['description'] ;?>
        <?php $i++;?>  
        <?php if(rehub_option('rehub_btn_text') !='') :?><?php $btn_txt = rehub_option('rehub_btn_text') ; ?><?php else :?><?php $btn_txt = esc_html__('Buy this item', 'rehub-theme') ;?><?php endif ;?>  
        <div class="rh_listofferitem rh_list_mbl_im_left border-grey-bottom<?php if ($i == 1){echo' best_price_item';}?>">
            <div class="rh-flex-center-align rh-flex-justify-center pt15 pb15 mobileblockdisplay">
                <div class="rh_listcolumn rh_listcolumn_image text-center">   
                    <a rel="nofollow sponsored" target="_blank" class="re_track_btn" href="<?php echo esc_url($afflink) ?>"<?php echo ''.$item['ga_event'] ?>>
                        <?php WPSM_image_resizer::show_static_resized_image(array('src'=> $aff_thumb, 'width'=> 90, 'title' => $offer_title, 'no_thumb_url' => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/default/noimage_123_90.png'));?>                                    
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="rh_listcolumn rh-flex-grow1 rh_listcolumn_text">
                    <h4 class="offer_title">
                        <a rel="nofollow sponsored" target="_blank" class="re_track_btn" href="<?php echo esc_url($afflink) ?>"<?php echo ''.$item['ga_event'] ?>>
                            <?php echo esc_attr($offer_title); ?>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                <?php if ($offer_desc): ?>
                    <div class="font80 greycolor lineheight20"><?php rehub_truncate('maxchar=150&text='.$offer_desc.''); ?></div>
                    <small class="small_size"><?php if ($item['in_stock']): ?><?php esc_html_e('Available: ', 'rehub-theme') ;?><span class="yes_available"><?php esc_html_e('In stock', 'rehub-theme') ;?></span><?php endif; ?></small>
                <?php endif; ?>                                
                </div>
                <div class="text-center rh_listcolumn_btn">
                    <div class="priced_block clearfix">
                        <?php if(!empty($offer_price)) : ?>
                            <div class="rh_price_wrapper mb5">
                                <span class="price_count">
                                    <ins class="rehub-main-color font110"><?php echo TemplateHelper::formatPriceCurrency($item['price_raw'], $item['currency_code'], '', ''); ?></ins>
                                    <?php if(!empty($offer_price_old)) : ?>
                                        <del><?php echo ''.$item['old_price_raw'];?></del>
                                    <?php endif ;?>                                      
                                </span>                        
                            </div>
                        <?php endif ;?>
                        <div>
                            <a class="re_track_btn btn_offer_block" href="<?php echo esc_url($afflink) ?>"<?php echo ''.$item['ga_event'] ?> target="_blank" rel="nofollow sponsored">
                                <?php echo esc_attr($btn_txt) ; ?>
                            </a>
                            <?php $offer_coupon_mask = 1 ?>
                            <?php if(!empty($item['extra']['coupon']['code_date'])) : ?>
                                <?php 
                                $timestamp1 = strtotime($item['extra']['coupon']['code_date']); 
                                $seconds = $timestamp1 - time(); 
                                $days = floor($seconds / 86400);
                                $seconds %= 86400;
                                if ($days > 0) {
                                  $coupon_text = $days.' '.__('days left', 'rehub-theme');
                                  $coupon_style = '';
                                }
                                elseif ($days == 0){
                                  $coupon_text = esc_html__('Last day', 'rehub-theme');
                                  $coupon_style = '';
                                }
                                else {
                                  $coupon_text = esc_html__('Coupon is Expired', 'rehub-theme');
                                  $coupon_style = 'expired_coupon';
                                }                 
                                ?>
                            <?php endif ;?>
                            <?php  if(!empty($item['extra']['coupon']['code'])) : ?>
                                <?php wp_enqueue_script('zeroclipboard'); ?>
                                <?php if ($offer_coupon_mask !='1' && $offer_coupon_mask !='on') :?>
                                    <div class="rehub_offer_coupon not_masked_coupon <?php if(!empty($item['extra']['coupon']['code_date'])) {echo ''.$coupon_style ;} ?>" data-clipboard-text="<?php echo esc_attr($item['extra']['coupon']['code']) ?>"><i class="rhicon rhi-scissors fa-rotate-180"></i><span class="coupon_text"><?php echo esc_attr($item['extra']['coupon']['code']) ?></span></div>   
                                <?php else :?>
                                    <?php wp_enqueue_script('affegg_coupons'); ?>
                                    <div class="rehub_offer_coupon masked_coupon <?php if(!empty($item['extra']['coupon']['code_date'])) {echo ''.$coupon_style ;} ?>" data-clipboard-text="<?php echo esc_attr($item['extra']['coupon']['code']) ?>" data-codetext="<?php echo esc_attr($item['extra']['coupon']['code']) ?>" data-dest="<?php echo esc_url($item['url']) ?>"<?php echo ''.$item['ga_event'] ?>><?php if(rehub_option('rehub_mask_text') !='') :?><?php echo rehub_option('rehub_mask_text') ; ?><?php else :?><?php esc_html_e('Reveal coupon', 'rehub-theme') ?><?php endif ;?><i class="rhicon rhi-external-link-square"></i></div>   
                                <?php endif;?>
                                <?php if(!empty($item['extra']['coupon']['code_date'])) {echo '<div class="time_offer">'.$coupon_text.'</div>';} ?>    
                            <?php endif ;?> 
                            <div class="aff_tag mt10"><?php echo rehub_get_site_favicon($item['orig_url']); ?></div>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                                                          
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php if (!empty($product_price_update)) :?>
        <div class="last_update"><?php esc_html_e('Last price update: ', 'rehub-theme'); ?><?php echo esc_attr($product_price_update) ;?></div>
    <?php endif ;?>
    <?php if ($see_more_uri): ?>
            <div class="text-center see-more-cat"> 
                <a rel="nofollow sponsored" target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url($see_more_uri); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('See more from category', 'rehub-theme');?></a>
            </div>
    <?php endif; ?>        
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

When we remove this part of the code:

```
// sort items by price
usort($items, function($a, $b) {
    if (!$a['price_raw']) return 1;
    if (!$b['price_raw']) return -1;
    return $a['price_raw'] - $b['price_raw'];
});
```

The sorting is not by price but it is sorting by "something". This is how we entered it in the CMS:

- Apple Macbook Pro 14"
- HP Pavillion 15"
- Lenovo Yoga Slim

But it is sorted like this:

- Lenovo Yoga Slim
- Apple Macbook Pro 14"
- HP Pavillion 15"

I just want to keep the sorting how I enter it in the CMS.

How can I DON'T sort by anything and just keep the order as I enter them?

Comment: This lacks details ... What CMS, what DBMS? Usually an order is not guaranteed by a database, you need to explicitly request a specific ordering. If your CMS does not store any value to indicate the order of the items - then you _might_ get the items in the order they were entered in - or you might not. Or you might get them ordered for a while - and then not any more, if something about the data changes, like a record "in the middle" gets deleted, and a new one inserted.

Comment: If you don't sort `$items`, it'll be displayed as-is. `foreach()` construct does not randomise arrays.

Comment: On a sidenote, items with no or falsy 'price_raw' values are pushed to the end of the array. The rest are sorted in ascending order based on their 'price_raw' values. if you don't want that to happen either make the sorting dynamic based on some setting or config, or remove the sorting code block in it's entirety. However, as said above, that does not guarantee that the order will remain the same in the future.